# integrate git bash in VS Code after update

Tags: git-bash

I updated VS Code from 1.66 to 1.84. Before update I was using git bash in the VS Code terminal. After update it isn´t available anymore. settings.json:

```
{
    "git.path": "D:\\Software\\git\\PortableGit\\bin\\git.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\Software\\git\\PortableGit\\bin\\bash.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this settings.json

```
{
    "git.path": "D:/Software/git/PortableGit/bin/git.exe",
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
            "Git Bash": {
                "path": "D:\\Software\\git\\PortableGit\\bin\\bash.exe",
                "icon": "terminal-bash"
            },            
    
            "gitbash": {
                "path": "D:\\Software\\git\\PortableGit\\bin\\bash.exe",
                "icon": "terminal-bash"
            }
        }
}
```